# Wait for function before executing other in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
async function getDetails() {
        var raw = JSON.stringify({
            "deliveryBoyName": userName,
        });

        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: raw
        };

        const result = await fetch(apiLink1, requestOptions);
        const jsonResult = await result.json();
        const routedetails = jsonResult.routedetails;

        if (currDetails.length === 0) {
            const promises = routedetails.map(element => {
                const raw1 = JSON.stringify({
                    "deliveryBoyName": "mikey",
                    "deliveryDate": "04-07-2023",
                    "orderPriority": (element.orderPriority + 30).toString()
                });

                const requestOptions1 = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    body: raw1
                };

                return fetch(apiLink2, requestOptions1)
                    .then(result => result.json())
                    .then(result => {
                        result = result.routedetails;
                        return result;
                    });
            });

            return Promise.all(promises)
                .then(results => {
                    setCurrDetails([...currDetails, ...results]);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                });


        }

    }


    async function setCurrentIndex() {
        setDeliveryNumber(currDetails[0][0].orderPriority);
        for (let i = 0; i < currDetails.length; i++) {
            if (currDetails[i][0].messagedates.length === 0) {
                setIndex(i);
                setDeliveryNumber(currDetails[i][0].orderPriority);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    async function setDetails() {
        await getDetails();
        await setCurrentIndex();
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setDetails();
    }, []);
```

In the above code actually **getDetails()** and **setCurrentIndex()** are main functions that need to be executed to update the data. In **getDetails()** function the state **currDetails** gets updated which I need to use in **setCurrentIndex()** function. With the help of async, await I expect that flow will be as such

**getDetails()** -> **setCurrentIndex()**

But it is not happening so, and I got **Promise rejection** warning. I have been trying this from really long time.

Thank you in advance for the solution.

Comment: `setCurrDetails` will not change `currDetails` in the same render cycle, no matter how long you will wait

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: *"and I got Promise rejection warning*" this means something within your async functions is going wrong ... You should fix that ... Typically there is more infomation on the error in the console log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use two different `useEffect` hooks. the problem is that `setCurrDetails` will only take effect after a render but you currently assume that it works right away. the comments by Konard are very accurate.

Answer (score 0):

using this code only when first api response come then after setCurrentIndex is called.

```
async function getDetails(callBack) {
var raw = JSON.stringify({
    "deliveryBoyName": userName,
});

const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: raw
};

const result = await fetch(apiLink1, requestOptions);
const jsonResult = await result.json();
const routedetails = jsonResult.routedetails;

if (currDetails.length === 0) {
    const promises = routedetails.map(element => {
        const raw1 = JSON.stringify({
            "deliveryBoyName": "mikey",
            "deliveryDate": "04-07-2023",
            "orderPriority": (element.orderPriority + 30).toString()
        });

        const requestOptions1 = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: raw1
        };

        return fetch(apiLink2, requestOptions1)
            .then(result => result.json())
            .then(result => {
                result = result.routedetails;
                return result;
            });
    });

    return Promise.all(promises)
        .then(results => {
            setCurrDetails([...currDetails, ...results]);
            callBack('success')
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });


}
```

}

```
async function setDetails() {
await getDetails((response) => {
  await setCurrentIndex();
});
```

}